# My index in dataframe is float, but I have this TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. What is worng with my code?

Tags: python, dataframe

First, sorry for my poor Eng since I am not native.
I have a dataframe which looks like this :

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA2O6.png)

You can see that so2 is in datatype float but when I apply this kind of code

```py
def SO2CAI(concatenated_df):
for concatenated_df['SO2'] in concatenated_df:
    if concatenated_df['SO2'] >= 0 and concatenated_df['SO2'] <= 0.020:
        SO2CAIdata =((IHI1-ILO1)/(SO2BPHI1 - SO2BPLO1)*(concatenated_df['SO2']-SO2BPLO1) + ILO1)
    elif concatenated_df['SO2'] >= 0.021 and concatenated_df['SO2'] <= 0.05:
        SO2CAIdata=((IHI2-ILO2)/(SO2BPHI2 - SO2BPLO2)*(concatenated_df['SO2']-SO2BPLO2) + ILO2)
    elif concatenated_df['SO2'] >= 0.051 and concatenated_df['SO2'] <= 0.15 :
        SO2CAIdata=((IHI3-ILO3)/(SO2BPHI3 - SO2BPLO3)*(concatenated_df['SO2']-SO2BPLO3) + ILO3)
    elif concatenated_df['SO2'] >= 0.151 and concatenated_df['SO2'] <= 1:
        SO2CAIdata=((IHI4-ILO4)/(SO2BPHI4 - SO2BPLO4)*(concatenated_df['SO2']-SO2BPLO4) + ILO4)
    return SO2CAIdata
print(SO2CAI(concatenated_df))
```

All the variable inside the code are in datatype float predefined

I get type error. what is the problem and how do I solve it.

Comment: Hi @kyle, could you also provide example input (as text, not screenshot) and expected output (as text also)? And also could you modify your code so that it runs and produces the error you mention?

Comment: @kyle you are using the wrong syntax for your for loop.  I suggest starting with https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: so, if so2 has 0.011 , then I want so2CAI function to run .  The function itself is just a simple math, and the answer from the math is add in to SO2CAIdata list. but i am having a problem in >= 0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kyle your function has many undefined variables (e.g., `IHI2`, `ILO2`, etc.). You have to declare them before referencing them.

Comment: @kyle Hi. Are you sure that `concatenated_df["SO2"].dtype` confirms the datatype is float? In case it's not, you can convert it into one `concatenated_df['SO2'] = concatenated_df['SO2'].astype(float)`

Comment: @BeniTrainor sorry all the undefined variables are defined before  (they are all float), but I thought showing them all in qustion would make it look dirty

Comment: @tebkanlo yes I've checked using  print(concatenated_df["SO2"].dtype )

Comment: No @kyle, it's okay to show. It's necessary that you provide a working example of code so that others can understand the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a number of undefined variables. However, the main problem with your code is its syntax. The correct form would be:

```
import pandas as pd

concatenated_df = pd.DataFrame([[0.11],[0.09],[0.10],[0.11]],columns=['SO2'])
IHI1=2
ILO1 =1
SO2BPHI1=3
IHI2 =4
ILO2 =6
SO2BPLO4 =8
SO2BPLO1 =9
SO2BPLO2 =10
SO2BPHI2 =12
ILO3 = 14
IHI4 =13
SO2BPLO3 =19
IHI3 =19
SO2BPHI3=20
SO2BPHI4 =17
ILO4= 21

def SO2CAI(concatenated_df):
    SO2CAIdata = []
    for i in concatenated_df['SO2']:
        if i >= 0 and i <= 0.020:
            SO2CAIdata.append(((IHI1-ILO1)/(SO2BPHI1 - SO2BPLO1)*(i-SO2BPLO1) + ILO1))
        elif i >= 0.021 and i<= 0.05:
            SO2CAIdata.append(((IHI2-ILO2)/(SO2BPHI2 - SO2BPLO2)*(i-SO2BPLO2) + ILO2))
        elif i >= 0.051 and i <= 0.15 :
            SO2CAIdata.append(((IHI3-ILO3)/(SO2BPHI3 - SO2BPLO3)*(i-SO2BPLO3) + ILO3))
        elif i >= 0.151 and i <= 1:
            SO2CAIdata.append(((IHI4-ILO4)/(SO2BPHI4 - SO2BPLO4)*(i-SO2BPLO4) + ILO4))
    concatenated_df['SO2CAIdata'] = SO2CAIdata
    return concatenated_df

print(SO2CAI(concatenated_df))
```

which results in the following output:

| SO2 | SO2CAIdata |
| --- | --- |
| 0.11 | -80.45 |
| 0.09 | -80.55 |
| 0.10 | -80.50 |
| 0.11 | -80.45 |

Note that I have arbitrarily defined the undefined variables.